# Windows Batch Script to Erase files with dual extensions

Tags: windows, batch-file, erase

I'm looking for a way to erase files that have an unusual dual extension.

I have files in this format:

> ```
> file1.ext1.ext2
> file1.ext2
> flie2.ext1.ext2
> file2.ext2
> file3.ext1.ext2
> file3.ext2
> ```

If I simply use a bat file like this:

```
call :obliterate "X:\path\to\files\1"
call :obliterate "X:\path\to\files\2"

goto :eof

:obliterate

cd %~1

X:

erase *.ext2 /s /F /Q

exit /b
```

Then it will remove all the files listed, because they are all basically `*.ext2`, but I would like to retain the `file?.ext1.ext2` ones.

Is it possible to do this in a batch script, or would I need to start learning VBA?

Comment: Just `del *.*.ext2`.

Comment: Hang on, this question is self-contradictory. At the start, you say you want to "erase files that have an unusual dual extension". At the end, you say you want to "retain the file?.ext1.ext2 ones". Which one do you want? Erase them or retain them?

Comment: Sorry.  I want to keep *.ext1.ext2 but kill *.ext2

Comment: In that case, my previous suggestion of `del *.*.ext2` is not what you want. You could do `copy *.*.ext2 some-temp-directory`, then delete whatever remains, and copy the files back here. There may be a better way, can't think of one right now.